# Using ODataQueryOptions and AutoMapper.ProjectTo fails unless I return a loaded collection

Tags: odata, automapper, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to separate my `OData` exposed entities from the real `data entities` so that the actual structure of my data entities is insulated from what is exposed on the API.

I tried following [this](https://d-fens.ch/2017/03/01/converting-odataqueryoptions-into-linq-expressions-in-c/) blog and create an helper class to abstract what is mentioned there so that my get function is something like this

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<Customer> options)
    {

        try
        {
            var collection = context.Set<CustomerEntity>();
            var queryable = ExpressionHelpers.GetEntity<Customer, CustomerEntity>(collection, options);
            IQueryable<Customer> result = queryable.ProjectTo<Customer>();

            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (ODataException ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

when i call in with the following parameter `odata/customer?$orderby=Id%20desc&$skip=1&$top=4`

this fails to return a proper json, I get an output as below.
`{"@odata.context":"http://localhost:63531/odata/$metadata#Customer","value":[`

as you can see its not fully formatted, however when I replace the following line

`IQueryable<Customer> result = queryable.ProjectTo<Customer>();`

with

`IQueryable<Customer> result = queryable.ProjectTo<Customer>().ToList();`

this works as expected.

**Interestingly**
 if I applied the `skip` and/or `take` in this IQueryable `result`, it works but I the results are not correct on the final output as I think it again applies the skip & top on the output of this function.

```
            IQueryable<Customer> result = queryable.ProjectTo<Customer>();
            if (options.Skip != null)
            {
                result = result.Skip(options.Skip.Value);
            }
            if (options.Top != null)
            {
                result = result.Take(options.Top.Value);
            }
            return Ok(result);
```

dose anyone here knows what am I missing ?

BTW my mappwe is configured as `Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<CustomerEntity, Customer>());`

***Update 1***
just updating the code to something like this also works

```
            IQueryable<Customer> result = queryable.ProjectTo<Customer>();
            result = result.Take(-1);
```

so the question is what is happening here? is adding `.Take` actually loads all the objects from the DB?

Comment: do you have any update for this question?